# Simple VB Print Function Taking Two Parameters

Tags: vba

I'm looking for a function that will take two parameters (a string and an integer) and print the string on a new line for each count of the integer.

For example, the parameters ("test", 2) would return:

```
test
test
```

I'm sure this is a simple bit of code, but I have never worked with VB before.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Constuntine had put me on the right path. The code I ended up using was:

```
Public Function printText(text As String, number As Integer)
    dim index as integer
    dim s as string = ""
    for index = 0 to number
      if index = number
         s = s + text
      else
         s = s + text + VBCRLF
      end if
    Next index
    return s
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic function that should accomplish what you need

```
Public Function printNumofTimes(text As String, number As Integer)
    for index = 1 to number                                 
        Debug.Print text
    Next index
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This isn't exactly what I needed, but it put me on the right path, and I was able to edit your code to do what I needed.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't give you what you needed. BUT at least you got to where you needed.

Answer (score 0):

This built-in method comes really close.  You just have to provide the "print" action.

```
Strings.StrDup(count, text + vbCrLf)
```